# Side-by-Side Configuration is incorrect

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I recently reformated which led me to install MSVC 2010. Everything seemed okay, except this time around I had Windows x64. I went ahead and rebuilt all of the dependencies for my project as x32 as some of them have issues with x64, but I am having this error message popup before my application even starts as debug build (it crashes immediately in release)

"This application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect."

I believe this is caused due to either my main project being written in MSVC9 and converted to MSVC2010 and/or my GUI library (CEGUI) doing the same thing.

Here is what my manifest looks like for my project...

```
   <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT' version='9.0.21022.8' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b' />
    </dependentAssembly>
```

I don't know how to fix this, so any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yup - this is because your project manifest is specifying the VC90 CRT, and you've build and linked your application with the VC10 import libraries.

I'd fix this by creating a dummy VC2010 C++ project that uses the DLL version of the CRT, and copy the CRT section(s) from it's manifest to your project manifest.